# Understanding disk partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ram, memory-usage

Ubuntu version: 16.04

I have both Windows 8 and Ubuntu installed on my laptop. Recently my lapotop has started functioning slowly and hence I looked into the memory partition. I have attached the o/p of sudo parted /dev/sda which show 10 partitions.

[image: parted screenshot]

Now I am a bit confused as to what is stored in each partition and whether it is advisable to dissolve any of these to improve efficiency and performance?

Comment: Welcome to AU. Computer memory doesn't have partitions. Did you mean to say disk partitions? In case you've attached a picture of a program window with an output you want us to see, please copy/paste that output into the question.

Comment: Unless your Ubuntu partition is (nearly) full ­— which is unlikely with its size of 278GB, but you can check with `df -h /` — the size of this partition or the size or pure existence of any other partition on your disk will not have any effect on Ubuntu's run-time performance at all. You should rather examine CPU and RAM usage, e.g. with `top` and `free -m`.

Comment: @mikewhatever You are right. I mean disk partitions. The output of the command sudo parted /dev/sda has been attached in the question.
I wanted to understand the significance of these partitions and why they are important.

Comment: The ESP - efi system partition is shared by all systems. Windows has these, vendors may add recovery or tools partitions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Linux has its standards base, but standard desktop installs are just / (root), swap does not have to be a partition anymore. You then can add /home or other ext4 data partitions.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard & 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base

Comment: So this machine has both windows and ubuntu and I want to understand two things, are 10 partitions absolutely necessary? Can some of the partitions be merged? What kind of effect would reducing partitions have on the performance?